# installing wine without internet

Tags: wine, video-player, media, media-manager

How to install wine application on ubuntu12.10 without internet. I have already downloaded wine 1.4, but I don't know how to install it.Please be sure any answer for me.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain how you downloaded it and the name of the file you downloaded, so we know what you have. Please also open a Terminal window (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run `apt-get -s install wine`. This will simulate an installation, revealing any other packages that are needed as dependencies. Please include all the text from the Terminal after that in your question also. You can format it with the `<$>` tool in the Ask Ubuntu editing toolbar. Also, you've tagged this video-player, media, and media-manager? If those tags are relevant, please explain how.

Answer (score 0):

How you install it will depend on the file type that you downloaded.

If it's a ".deb" file, then just double-clicking it should make it run and install. If that doesn't work, then open terminal, `cd` to where the file is, and run it from there (something like `sudo name-of-installer-file.deb`).

If it's a ".tar.gz" file, then it will be more involved. [WineHQ has good information on how to do this, though.](http://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) See the "installing without an internet connection" section.

In short, what you'll need to do is use a computer that does have a connection to download the necessary dependencies and copy them to a USB stick or external drive that you can then plug into the computer without a connection. Then, on the non-connected machine, `cd` in terminal to where those files are and run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` to install everything.

On a side note, I noticed you tagged this question with "video-player", "media", and "media-manager". Ubuntu comes with a video player (Totem) and music manager (Rhythmbox), and there are a number of other such applications that work well, run natively, and are compatible with most MP3 players. It may be worthwhile to try them, instead, which you would install the same way as you would install Wine. The advantage to this would be that you'd install far less (to compare, installing Wine on a computer with a high speed connection can still take upwards of 10-20 minutes to download and install everything, and often needs other libraries installed to provide the necessary support). It's usually a good idea to try native applications, first.